# Where do I download installer for MS SQL Server 2005 ODBC connectivity drivers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, windows-installer

Okay I give up, where do I download an installer for the MS SQL Server 2005 ODBC driver that I can distribute to our users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The first hit in Google for "ms sql 2005 odbc driver download"](http://www.google.com.ua/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ms+sql+2005+odbc+driver+download) is [this article](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d09c1d60-a13c-4479-9b91-9e8b9d835cdc&displaylang=en):

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client
>   (SQL Native Client) is a single
>   dynamic-link library (DLL) containing
>   both the SQL OLE DB provider and SQL
>   ODBC driver. It contains run-time
>   support for applications using
>   native-code APIs (ODBC, OLE DB and
>   ADO) to connect to Microsoft SQL
>   Server 7.0, 2000 or 2005. SQL Native
>   Client should be used to create new
>   applications or enhance existing
>   applications that need to take
>   advantage of new SQL Server 2005
>   features. This redistributable
>   installer for SQL Native Client
>   installs the client components needed
>   during run time to take advantage of
>   new SQL Server 2005 features, and
>   optionally installs the header files
>   needed to develop an application that
>   uses the SQL Native Client API.

And there's a [download link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/4/D/44DBDE61-B385-4FC2-A67D-48053B8F9FAD/sqlncli.msi) under this text.
Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for.  Didn't scroll down to the description at the bottom of the page, the giant list of files scared me off before I got there.

Comment: Dead link to MSI.

Comment: @VictorioBerra sorry for not keeping the link alive for you all these 11 years.

Comment: That's fair, but id like people to see this before they get hit with the disappointment of clicking the link.